# how to parse a specific json string that does not work with traditional json parsers

Tags: .net, json

I have the following json string and would like to get the values of the "message" which all contains more or less the same format. The usual code I have does not work:

```
        Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(data)
        Dim skipFlag As Boolean = False

        Dim token As JToken = JObject.Parse(data)
        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jobj.Children().ToList


        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            If item.Name = "error" Then

            End If
        Next
```

only one value is returned and not sure how to capture the values.

```
 {"error":      
 {"message":

     "Rule '\"CVS_Extra ' is invalid.  mismatched character '<EOF>' 
         expecting '\"' (at position 21)\nno viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
     \nRule '\"walgreens.com\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid. 
          mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 45)
     \nRule '\"walgreen's\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid.  
          mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 42)
    \nRule '\"cvs.com\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid.  
          mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 39)
    \nRule '\"C V S\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid.  
          mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 37)
    \nRule '\"H E Butt\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid. 
         mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 40)
    \nRule '\"H-E-B\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid.  
          mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 37)
    \nRule '\"HEB.com\" TX a prescription\" ' is invalid. 
            mismatched character '<EOF>' expecting '\"' (at position 39)

              \n","sent":"2013-08-09T15:49:51+00:00"}}
```

Comment: Is this your entire pseuso_JSON? Is this `{"error": e")  ` as in the json? (first row)

Comment: oops sorry let me correct that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give it to you in C#... but converting in VB.NET should be easy.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json); // json == your json

JObject error = obj["error"] as JObject;

if (error != null)
{
    JValue message = error["message"] as JValue;

    if (message != null)
    {
        // found
    }
}
```

In VB.NET should be:

```
Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(json) ' json is your json

Dim jerror As JObject = TryCast(jobj("error"), JObject)

If jerror IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim jmessage As JValue = TryCast(jerror("message"), JValue)

    If jmessage IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim message As String = jmessage.Value(Of String)()
        Dim lines As String() = message.Replace(vbCrLf, vbCr & vbCr).Split(New String()() = { vbLf }, StringSplitOptions.None).[Select](Function(p As String) p.Replace(vbCr & vbCr, vbCrLf)).ToArray(Of String)()
    End If
End If
```

(changed the names of the variables because `error` is a reserved word in VB.NET)

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to get each \n Rule value? Really appreciate your response

Comment: @vbNewbie You want to split the text by the \n?

Comment: yes, But I think I figured it out. I just took the output I get from above and split via string

Comment: @vbNewbie I've inserted some lines that should split it, but it all depends on how the newlines are made... You can try it.